# How to match a word using a given character only once

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm trying to find a regex pattern to match a word with some given characters. But each character should be used only once. For example if I'm given "**yrarbil**" (library backwards), it should match these:

- library
- rar
- lib
- rarlib

But it should not match the following

- libraryy ("y" is used more times than given)
- libraries ("i" is used more times than given, and also "es" are not given at all)

I've searched all around but best I could find was code to match a word but the same character is used more than the amount of times it was given. Thank you.

P.S: If this can't be done in regex (I'm a noob at it as you can see) what would be the best way to match a word like this programmatically?

Comment: A regex won't be efficient for that. A solution would be to simply count the caracters of your list.

Comment: I think it must be done with hand not regex, but which language you understand better C++ or c#?

Comment: @shA.t library is valid because at the given word yrarbil r is used twice...

Comment: @dystroy Well I thought it would work .-. :D

Comment: @ahmedsafan86 C# would be better.

Comment: @E.Hoxha C# code is post in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"library" is confusing because it has 2 litters r. But it is solvable from my opinion.

Easily Create a `map<char, int>` this will store the count of each character in the pattern. Then we will generate a `map<char, int>` for word to check, it will also contain the count of each char then iterate over the map if any char has more count than the same char in the map of pattern it don't match, also if it is not found at all then it don't match also.

As required the code in C#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool Match(string pattern, string toMatch)
        {
            Dictionary<char, int> patternMap = new Dictionary<char, int>();
            Dictionary<char, int> toMatchMap = new Dictionary<char, int>();

            foreach (char ch in pattern)
            {
                if (patternMap.ContainsKey(ch))
                    ++patternMap[ch];
                else
                    patternMap[ch] = 1;
            }
            foreach (char ch in toMatch)
            {
                if (toMatchMap.ContainsKey(ch))
                    ++toMatchMap[ch];
                else
                    toMatchMap[ch] = 1;
            }

            foreach (var item in toMatchMap)
            {
                if (!patternMap.ContainsKey(item.Key) || patternMap[item.Key] < item.Value)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = "library";
            string[] test = { "lib", "rarlib", "rarrlib", "ll" };
            foreach (var item in test)
            {
                if(Match(pattern, item))
                    Console.WriteLine("Match item : {0}", item);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed item : {0}", item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            /*
Match item : lib
Match item : rarlib
Failed item : rarrlib
Failed item : ll

             */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex won't work for that. A solution would be to simply count the caracters of your list.

For example in JavaScript:

```js
function count(str){
  return str.split('').reduce(function(m,c){
     m[c] = (m[c]||0)+1;
     return m;
  },{})
}
function check(str, reference){
   var ms = count(str), mr = count(reference);
   for (var k in ms) {
     if (!(ms[k]<=mr[k])) return false;
   }
   return true;
}

// what follows is only for demonstration in a snippet
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#r').text(check($('#a').val(), "library") ? "OK":"NOT OK");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=a value="rarlib">
<button>CHECK</button>
<div id=r></div>
```

Comment: As the other guys suggested seems that this is the way. Thank you for this :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why do you want to do this using a regexp when a very simple and straightforward solution is available.

You just count how much times each letter appears in a given word, and in a word you test. Then you check that each letter in a tested word appears no more times than in a given word.

```
for ch in given_word
    cnt[ch]++
for ch in test_word
    cnt[ch]--
for ch='a'..'z'
    if cnt[ch]<0
        answer is no
if for all leters cnt[ch]>=0 
    answer is yes
```

Comment: Well I'll have a look at this one. I'll get back as soon as I try this out. Thank you.